# How can I drag the first element of a list, to a location on my calendar using selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

My list is always different, I can't use an id because it will always change, I can't use the xpath of that element. I need to find a way to always take the first element and set it in the location I am telling him to. 
I attached a print screen with what I want to do. 
[image]

Comment: It is close to impossible to give a good answer without having the HTML source code of your page (try to post the relevant parts only). Thanks.

Comment: @Oana see the two 'Linked' on the right for helpful info

Comment: dragAndDropToObject 
Target: //html/body/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/ul/div[1] - it's the first div of an ul, so I can always set my first element from a list.
Value: The location where I want to set it by id: id=165b3d9e-07a9-4c17-95a6-0713ec379f93_0_26

Answer (score 0):

The question is a dupe of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2622/8992

You can drag with

```
# example is in ruby
driver.action.drag_and_drop(element, target).perform
```

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#drag-and-drop

But not sure if that is available in the seleniumIDE.

Your other question (its better if you only ask 1 thing per question btw) is how to deal with dynamic id's and selecting stuff in a table.

That is a separate question that you could post or you could also see if it is covered by:

[How to handle dynamic changing ID's In XPath?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath)

and others under the search https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=dynamic+id

Comment: the drag and drop commands you usually use did not help me in this situation and this was not a drop down :) I found my answer, see above. Thank you.